# Why does my fridge only cool the top two shelves?

Tags: refrigerator, cooling

Fridge doesn't cool properly. Bosch thermostat is blinking and only the top two shelves are cool. The temperature increases as you go down the shelves. The bottom shelf is almost at room temperature.

Appliances repair guy turned up and checked the temperature in different spots and says the gas needs refilling and motor needs replacing. He didn't even check the back nor did he unmount the fridge. Just used a thermometer!!

What's wrong with my fridge?

Comment: How long has it been like this?  Did it sit for a while unplugged / empty?  Why do you doubt the repair guy's opinion?

Comment: It sounds like a bad fan to me.

Comment: @IronEagle, it's been like this for about 5 days now. The refrigator door was left open for about an hour whilst it was quite hot outside. Doubt the repair guy as he came to the conclusion using a thermometer and within a minute!

Comment: @Gil, how do I check if it's the fan?

Comment: How cool is cool? What is the temperature at the top and bottom.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not familiar with that unit and without more information I cannot answer that question. Check on line for the service manual, that should show where it is.